# Changing colors of grid cells by clicking on them

Tags: java, swing, graph, graphics

I am working on program which is drawing a grid of cells. Each cell has specified color and one of four states:

1.
STARTCELL //marked by yellow color
2.
ENDCELL //marked by red color
3.
EMPTYCELL //marked by white color
4.
BLOCKEDCELL // marked by black color

At the beginning there are one yellow cell, and one red cell and the rest of them are white.

I wanted to be able to change the colors and states of cells by clicking on them and after some research I found the solution:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (Cell item : gridCells) {
        if (item.getCellShape().contains(e.getPoint())&& item.getCellState()==CellState.EMPTYCELL) {
            item.setCellColor(mouseColor);
            if(mouseColor==startCellColor){
                item.setCellState(CellState.STARTCELL);
            }else if(mouseColor==endCellColor){
                item.setCellState(CellState.ENDCELL);
            }else{
                item.setCellState(CellState.BLOCKEDCELL);
            }
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
```

The only problem is there should be only one `STARTCELL`
and one `ENDCELL`at the time and I can't find a way to properly change states of non clicked cells.

I tried many times and ended up with this:

```
    @Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (Cell item : gridCells) {
        if (item.getCellShape().contains(e.getPoint())&& item.getCellState()==CellState.EMPTYCELL) {
            item.setCellColor(mouseColor);
            if(mouseColor==startCellColor){
                    gridCells.get(numberOfStartCell-1).setCellColor(cellColor);
                    gridCells.get(numberOfStartCell-1).setCellState(CellState.EMPTYCELL);
                    numberOfStartCell=item.getNumberOfCell();
                    item.setCellState(CellState.STARTCELL);
            }else if(mouseColor==endCellColor){
                item.setCellState(CellState.ENDCELL);
            }else{
                item.setCellState(CellState.BLOCKEDCELL);
            }
            areaTest.setText(Integer.toString(numberOfStartCell));
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work correctly. After the first click the color of the new cell changes to yellow the old one became white, and value of variable `numberOfStartCell` also changes. But after the second click and so on the only part which changes is `numberOfStartCell`.

Here is MCV:
Nothing to explain in first two classes I guess.

`Class Main`

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyFrame();
            }
        });
     }
}
```

`Class MyFrame`

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
 
   int width  = 750;
   int height = 750;
   MyPanel panel;

   public MyFrame() {
        super("Przeszukiwanie");
        setSize(width,height);
        setResizable(false);

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double screenWidth = screenSize.getWidth();
        double ScreenHeight = screenSize.getHeight();
        int x = ((int)screenWidth-width)/2;
        int y = ((int)ScreenHeight-height)/2;

        setLocation(x,y);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        panel=new MyPanel();
        add(panel);
        pack();
    }
}
```

`Class MyPanel` takes care of event handling and GUI.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private JButton createButton;

    private ButtonGroup cellColorGroup;
    private JRadioButton startingNode;
    private JRadioButton endingNode;
    private JRadioButton obstacleNode;

    private JTextField rows;
    private JTextField columns;

    private JLabel labelRows;
    private JLabel labelColumns;

    private String strRowsField;
    private String strColumnsField;

    private JPanel panelButtons;
    private GridPanel panelGrid;
    private JPanel panelSettings;

    public MyPanel(){

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 600));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        strRowsField="10";
        strColumnsField="10";

        panelButtons=new JPanel();
        panelSettings=new JPanel();
        panelGrid=new GridPanel(Integer.parseInt(strColumnsField),Integer.parseInt(strRowsField));

        panelSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2));

        createButton= new JButton("Create");

        cellColorGroup=new ButtonGroup();
        startingNode=new JRadioButton("Strating Node");
        endingNode=new JRadioButton("Ending Node");
        obstacleNode=new JRadioButton("Remove/Add Obstacle", true);

        cellColorGroup.add(startingNode);
        cellColorGroup.add(endingNode);
        cellColorGroup.add(obstacleNode);

        createButton.addActionListener(this);
        startingNode.addActionListener(this);
        endingNode.addActionListener(this);
        obstacleNode.addActionListener(this);

        columns=new JTextField(strColumnsField,2);
        rows=new JTextField(strRowsField,2);
        labelRows=new JLabel("Number of rows");
        labelColumns= new JLabel("Number of columns");

        panelButtons.add(createButton);

        panelSettings.add(labelColumns);
        panelSettings.add(columns);
        panelSettings.add(labelRows);
        panelSettings.add(rows);
        panelSettings.add(startingNode);
        panelSettings.add(endingNode);
        panelSettings.add(obstacleNode);

        add(panelButtons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(panelGrid,BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(panelSettings,BorderLayout.EAST);

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == createButton) {
            panelGrid.setcNodes(Integer.parseInt(columns.getText()));
            panelGrid.setrNodes(Integer.parseInt(rows.getText()));
            panelGrid.getGridCells().clear();
            panelGrid.repaint();
        }else if(e.getSource() == startingNode){
             panelGrid.setMouseColor(panelGrid.getStartCellColor());

        }else if(e.getSource() == endingNode){
            panelGrid.setMouseColor(panelGrid.getEndCellColor());

        }else if(e.getSource() == obstacleNode){
             panelGrid.setMouseColor(panelGrid.getObstacleCellColor());
        }
    }
}
```

`Class GridPanel` takes care of drawing nodes, edges and cells.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private int cNodes;//Number of nodes across
    private int rNodes;//Number of nodes along
    private int nodeX;//X coordinate of the first node
    private int nodeY;//Y coordinate of the first node
    private int width=330;
    private int height=330;
    private int circleX;//Center of circle X
    private int circleY;//Center of circle Y
    private Color cellColor;
    private Color startCellColor;
    private Color endCellColor;
    private Color obstacleCellColor;
    private Color mouseColor;
    private int numberOfStartCell;

    private ArrayList<Cell> gridCells;
    public GridPanel(int cNodes, int rNodes){

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));

        this.cNodes=cNodes;
        this.rNodes=rNodes;

        if(cNodes>rNodes){
            nodeX=width/(cNodes+1);//Calculation of the x coordinate value of the first node
            nodeY=height/(cNodes+1);//Calculation of the y coordinate value of the first node
        }else{
            nodeX=width/(rNodes+1);
            nodeY=height/(rNodes+1);
        }

        circleX=nodeX;
        circleY=nodeY;

        cellColor=Color.WHITE;
        startCellColor=Color.YELLOW;
        endCellColor=Color.RED;
        obstacleCellColor=Color.BLACK;

        gridCells=new ArrayList<Cell>();

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        drawCells(g2d);

     }
    
    public void drawCells(Graphics2D g2d){
        int number=0;
        int c=0;
        for(int i=0; i<rNodes; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<cNodes; j++){
                number++;
                if(i==0 && j==cNodes-1){
                     gridCells.add(new Cell(circleX,circleY,nodeX,endCellColor,new Rectangle2D.Double(circleX-(nodeX/2),circleY-(nodeX/2),nodeX,nodeX),CellState.ENDCELL,number));

                }
                 else if(i==rNodes-1 && j==0){
                     gridCells.add(new Cell(circleX,circleY,nodeX,startCellColor,new Rectangle2D.Double(circleX-(nodeX/2),circleY-(nodeX/2),nodeX,nodeX),CellState.STARTCELL,number));
                numberOfStartCell=number;
                }
                 else {
                     gridCells.add(new Cell(circleX,circleY,nodeX,cellColor,new Rectangle2D.Double(circleX-(nodeX/2),circleY-(nodeX/2),nodeX,nodeX),CellState.EMPTYCELL,number));
                }
                g2d.setPaint(gridCells.get(c).getCellColor());
                g2d.fill(gridCells.get(c).getCellShape());
                g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.draw(gridCells.get(c).getCellShape());
                if(j<(cNodes-1)){
                    circleX+=nodeX;
                }
                c++;
            }
            circleX=nodeX;
            if(i<(rNodes-1)){
                circleY+=nodeY;
            }
        }
        circleX=nodeX;
        circleY=nodeY;
    }

    public void setMouseColor(Color mouseColor) {
        this.mouseColor = mouseColor;
    }

    public void setcNodes(int cNodes) {
        this.cNodes = cNodes;
    }

    public void setrNodes(int rNodes) {
        this.rNodes = rNodes;
    }   

    public Color getObstacleCellColor() {
        return obstacleCellColor;
    }

    public Color getStartCellColor() {
        return startCellColor;
    }

    public Color getEndCellColor() {
        return endCellColor;
    }

    public ArrayList<Cell> getGridCells() {
        return gridCells;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (Cell item : gridCells) {
            if (item.getCellShape().contains(e.getPoint())&& item.getCellState()==CellState.EMPTYCELL) {
                item.setCellColor(mouseColor);
                if(mouseColor==startCellColor){
                        gridCells.get(numberOfStartCell-1).setCellColor(cellColor);
                        gridCells.get(numberOfStartCell-1).setCellState(CellState.EMPTYCELL);
                        numberOfStartCell=item.getNumberOfCell();
                        item.setCellState(CellState.STARTCELL);
                }else if(mouseColor==endCellColor){
                    item.setCellState(CellState.ENDCELL);
                }else{
                    item.setCellState(CellState.BLOCKEDCELL);
                }
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

`Class Cell` has information about cells (state, color, number..).

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.Shape;
    import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
    import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
    import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
    import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

    public class Cell implements Shape{
    
        private int centerX;
        private int centerY;
        private double side;
        private Color cellColor;
        private double x;
        private double y;
        private Shape cellShape;
        private CellState cellState;
        private int numberOfCell;
    
        public Cell(int centerX, int centerY, int side, Color cellColor,Shape cellShape, CellState cellState,int numberOfCell){
            super();
            this.centerX=centerX;
            this.centerY=centerY;
            this.side=side;
            this.cellColor=cellColor;
            this.cellShape=cellShape;
            this.cellState=cellState;
            this.numberOfCell=numberOfCell;
        }
    public Shape getCellShape() {
        return cellShape;
    }

    public int getNumberOfCell() {
        return numberOfCell;
    }

    public Color getCellColor() {
        return cellColor;
    }

    public void setCellColor(Color cellColor) {
        this.cellColor = cellColor;
    }

    public void setCellShape(Shape cellShape) {
        this.cellShape = cellShape;
    }
    
    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public CellState getCellState() {
        return cellState;
    }

    public void setCellState(CellState cellState) {
        this.cellState = cellState;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Point2D p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Rectangle2D r) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(double x, double y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public Rectangle2D getBounds2D() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public PathIterator getPathIterator(AffineTransform at) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public PathIterator getPathIterator(AffineTransform at, double flatness) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean intersects(Rectangle2D r) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean intersects(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

`Class CellState`

```
public enum CellState {

    STARTCELL,ENDCELL,EMPTYCELL,BLOCKEDCELL;
}
```

Comment: Suggestions: 1) try to use a M-V-C structure for your program, 2) distill your code into a valid [mcve] and post that code here so that we can compile and run it, experience the problem first and and thus fully understand it. Yes this is asking  a **lot** of extra effort from you, but it makes your question **much** easier to answer, and so help **you** in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a chapter and verse answer, not without your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I can give you a large suggestion. Note that selecting empty and and blocked cells is logically a very different thing from selecting starting and ending cells, and so your code should do these things in very different ways. What I would do, is in the mouse listener, check which button is pressed. If the left button (the standard button), toggle the cells blocked / empty state (but only if it's not already a start or end cell). If the right mouse button is pressed (or alt-mouse if there is no mouse button), then display a pop-up menu to allow the user to select the cell as the start or end cell. The code for selecting start or end would be separate from the empty/block toggle code, would first iterate through the model, clearing the former start or end cell, and then setting it.

If you want a better more complete solution, again, please post your valid [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code here with your question (not in a link).

Luck.